# Terminal can't print vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ and trying my hands on `std::vector`. But for some reason even a single `std::cout` doesn't work with the `vector` I have declared.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::vector <int> test_score;
    test_score.push_back(10);
    cout << test_score.at(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The terminal output shows nothing. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsKs4.png) it is.
The same code works fine on IDEs like CodeBlocks.

Comment: Works fine for me. What do you get in the terminal? Nothing? How are you compiling and running it?

Comment: Which terminal you using? What's the operating system?

Comment: command line terminal with visual studios

Comment: I see that in the image, you are not specifying the output file's name. Try `g++ -Wall -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main.exe && main.exe`. What do you get?

Comment: I am on windows, still no output maybe the gcc-g++ compiler did not install properly, but normal i/o codes compile and run just fine

Comment: add `cout << endl` I'm suspecting buffer is not flushed.

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work

Comment: To be clear, does a simple `std::cout << "Hello world\n";` work on the VS code integrated terminal? Have you already tried on an actual terminal?

Comment: type in terminal `more main.cpp` maybe by mistake you are using different source.

Comment: Yes it does print Hello world on the VS code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your info, your code works fine on my terminal without the image description part.

Maybe try to comment these lines out as they are not involve in the problem or try to compile a Hello World program first may help.

Comment: Everything else works okay, just the vector cout statement is creating a problem